# Objeto não encontrado! error 404 xamp

Tags: php, php-7

Neste projeto estou com problema em encontrar a rota /admin que criei, acessando o index do site('/') a rota que foi definida funciona normalmente, entretanto acessar o index do admin('/admin') o arquivo não é encontrado. Código:
Index da página

```
<?php 

require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

use \Slim\Slim;
use \Hcode\Page;
use \Hcode\PageAdmin;

$app = new Slim();

$app->config('debug', true);

$app->get('/', function() {

    $page = new Page();
    $page->setTpl("index");


});

$app->get('/admin', function() {

    $page = new PageAdmin();
    $page->setTpl("index");


});

$app->run();

 ?>
```

Classe Page (fornece o template ao index):

```
<?php 

namespace Hcode;

use Rain\Tpl;

class Page {

    private $tpl;
    private $options = [];
    private $defaults = [
        "header"=>true,
        "footer"=>true,
        "data"=>[]
    ];

    public function __construct($opts = array(), $tpl_dir = "/views/")
    {

        $this->options = array_merge($this->defaults, $opts);
...
```

Classe PageAdmin (fornece o template a página /admin):

```
<?php

namespace Hcode;

class PageAdmin extends Page{

    public function __construct($opts = array(), $tpl_dir = "/views/admin/"){
        parent::__construct($opts, $tpl_dir);
    }

}
```

Consegui acessar a classe Page e PageAdmin pela rota index('/'), entretanto, pela rota do admin('/admin') o seguinte erro de objeto não encontrado Error 404 é retornado.

Answer (score 0):

Bom Dia, estou com o mesmo problema, empacado a 2 dias para falar a verdade.
Percebi que e um problema de rota, pois se você alterar o index.php retirar o /admin,
ele consegue acessar o administrativo,porém para de acessar a index do site.

$app->get('/(retirei admin)', function() {

```
$page = new PageAdmin(); 

$page->setTpl("index");
```

});

Ou ele não está conseguindo acessar a subpasta "views/admin/index.html" ou há algum erro na pagina page.php, pois a pageadmin.php apenas herda da mesma.

Caso você tenha conseguido resolver, poderia postar a solução?

Continuarei pesquisando e testando, caso eu consiga resolver e ainda esteja aberto esse tópico, eu lhe informo a resolução. Um abraço.

Comment: Ainda não resolvi, inclusive não dei continuidade nesse projeto por causa desse problema, mas futuramente vou tentar resolver, se eu conseguir eu posto aqui. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Fala Xará, tudo bem? Consegui rodar, porém não utilizei a classe `Extend` (*herança*),
Estou postando pois pode ser que mais pessoas estejam no mesmo ponto em que eu estava, então basicamente eu refiz o **PageAdmin** semelhante ao **Page**, porém mudando o `tpl_dir`.
Basicamente um redudancia, mas que me permitiu seguir adiante no curso.
 Espero Que lhe ajude caso queria retormar as aulas. Um Abraço.

```
<?php 

namespace Controller; //Substitua Controller por Hcode caso vc tenha feito igual ao curso

use Rain\Tpl;

class PageAdmin {

    private $tpl;
    private $options = [];
    private $defaults = [
        "data"=>[]
    ];

    public function __construct($opts = array()){

    $this->options = array_merge($this->defaults, $opts);

    $config = array(
    "tpl_dir"       => "views/admin/",
    "cache_dir"     => "views-cache/",  
    "debug"         => false
    );

    Tpl::configure( $config );

    $this->tpl = new Tpl;

    $this->setData($this->options["data"]);

    $this->tpl->draw("header");

    }

    private function setData($data = array()){

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        $this->tpl->assign($key, $value);
    }
}

    public function setTpl($name, $data = array(), $returnHTML = false){

        $this->setData($data);

        return $this->tpl->draw($name, $returnHTML);
    }

    public function __destruct(){

        $this->tpl->draw("footer");

    }

}

?>
```

> OBSERVAÇÃO: Ele utiliza `"tpl_dir" => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$tpl_dir`, Porém no meu não deu certo, então deixei da forma simplificada.
>
> OBSERVAÇÃO2: Inclua o `"debug"=> false`, sem o mesmo não funcionou.